# Prevent a bash script from terminating after handling a SIGINT

Tags: linux, bash, signals, bash-trap

I am writing a bash wrapper for an application. This wrapper is responsible for changing the user, running the software and logging its output.
I also want it to propagate the SIGINT signal.

Here is my code so far :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e; set -u

function child_of {
    ps --ppid $1 -o "pid" --no-headers | head -n1
}

function handle_int {
    echo "Received SIGINT"
    kill -int $(child_of $SU_PID)
}

su myuser -p -c "bash /opt/loop.sh 2>&1 | tee -i >(logger -t mytag)" &
SU_PID=$!

trap "handle_int" SIGINT

wait $SU_PID
echo "This is the end."
```

My problem is that when I send a SIGINT to this wrapper, `handle_int` gets called but then the script is over, while I want it to continue to wait for `$SU_PID`.

Is there a way to catch the int signal, do something and then prevent the script from terminating ?

Comment: If I understand your question: after receiving `SIGINT` you want your wrapper script to wait until your `su` command dies before exiting?

Comment: @rkyser Yes that is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a gotcha: after Ctrl-C, "This is the end." is expected but it never comes because the script has exited prematurely. The reason is `wait` has (unexpectedly) returned non-zero while running under `set -e`.

According to "man bash":

> If  bash  is  waiting  for a command to complete and receives a signal for which a trap has been set, the trap
>   will not be executed until the command completes.  When bash is waiting for an **asynchronous  command**  via  the
>   **wait  builtin**,  the  reception of a signal for which a **trap has been set** will cause the wait builtin to return
>   immediately with an **exit status greater than 128**, immediately after which the trap is executed.

You should wrap your `wait` call in `set +e` so that your program can continue running after handling a trapped signal while waiting for an asynchronous command.

Like this:

```
# wait function that handles trapped signal on asynchronous commands.
function safe_async_wait {
  set +e
  wait $1 # returns >128 on asynchronous commands
  set -e
}
#...
safe_async_wait $SU_PID
```